# How to print 2 lists vertically next to each other?

Tags: python-3.x

I know how to print a list vertically :

```
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

Output :

```
43435
23423
```

however I want to put another list (called items2) next to each other so the out put is like this :

```
43435  a
23423  a
```

how can I do this in the simplest way ?

EDIT:

```
86947367 banana
 2 10
78364721 apple
 2 6
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip):

```
list_a = [43435, 23423]
list_b = ['a', 'b']

for item_a, item_b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    print(item_a, item_b)

>> 43435 a
   23423 b
```

This can be generalized to a varying number of lists, as long as you keep your lists in a list:

```
list_a = [43435, 23423]
list_b = ['a', 'b']
list_c = ['ca', 'cb']

list_of_lists = [list_a, list_b, list_c]

for a in zip(*list_of_lists):
    print(*a)

>> 43435 a ca
   23423 b cb
```

Comment: what is the asterisk for ?

Comment: thats really weird I did exactly what you did and only 2 out of 4 lists where in a horizontal line , the other 2 where below.Look at Edit above.

Comment: @Mikel.JKK It is used for unpacking, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/4282/list-destructuring-aka-packing-and-unpacking/14982/packing-function-arguments#t=2016083014463140162

Comment: Also , i swapped the order around (of the 4 lists) and only the last one did not go onto the horizontal line , I think it is because I have converted 2 of my lists into an integer.

Comment: @Mikel.JKK You will have to provide your whole (relevant) code,

Comment: yes I kept the 2 lists (integer ones) in the middle of the order and all 4 are now in a horizontal line . Why is this ?

Comment: @Mikel.JKK It is impossible to tell without seeing your actual code.

Comment: I can't over 30,000 characters.

Comment: I have 4 lists items , product_list , items2 and price_list . I need to rpint them in this order. lists items2 and price_list are integers (so no quote marks when printed). That is why they are not joining the horizontal line , how do i return the quote marks ?